# How to average and estimate data in R

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
            id power  training     hr percent_absVO2 percent_power    relVO2 percent_relVO2
1  AC12-PRD-C1    25    linear  88.75       49.34068      21.73913  8.797619       49.34068
2  AC12-PRD-C1    40    linear  93.25       54.73210      34.78261  9.758929       54.73210
3  AC12-PRD-C1    55    linear  99.75       63.51193      47.82609 11.324405       63.51193
4  AC12-PRD-C1    70    linear 109.75       71.79102      60.86957 12.800595       71.79102
5  AC12-PRD-C1    85    linear 118.75       80.05341      73.91304 14.273810       80.05341
6  AC12-PRD-C1   100    linear 127.00       89.85144      86.95652 16.020833       89.85144
7  AC12-PRD-C1   115    linear 135.75      100.00000     100.00000 17.830357      100.00000
8  AC12-PRD-C2    25    linear  84.25       40.10378      17.24138  7.974646       40.10378
9  AC12-PRD-C2    40    linear  89.25       43.49889      27.58621  8.649764       43.49889
10 AC12-PRD-C2    55    linear  96.25       49.54781      37.93103  9.852594       49.54781
11 AC12-PRD-C2    70    linear 102.25       63.00964      48.27586 12.529481       63.00964
12 AC12-PRD-C2    85    linear 110.75       70.02224      58.62069 13.923939       70.02224
13 AC12-PRD-C2   100    linear 118.25       80.11861      68.96552 15.931604       80.11861
14 AC12-PRD-C2   115    linear 129.25       89.34025      79.31034 17.765330       89.34025
15 AC12-PRD-C2   130    linear 136.25       93.29874      89.65517 18.552476       93.29874
16 AC12-PRD-C2   145    linear 147.50      100.00000     100.00000 19.885024      100.00000
17 AL13-PRD-C1    25 nonlinear  69.50       41.36691      19.23077  7.733918       41.36691
18 AL13-PRD-C1    40 nonlinear  73.00       46.82515      30.76923  8.754386       46.82515
19 AL13-PRD-C1    55 nonlinear  83.25       53.48764      42.30769 10.000000       53.48764
20 AL13-PRD-C1    70 nonlinear  93.75       61.58899      53.84615 11.514620       61.58899
21 AL13-PRD-C1    85 nonlinear 104.50       71.91117      65.38462 13.444444       71.91117
22 AL13-PRD-C1   100 nonlinear 114.25       84.23522      76.92308 15.748538       84.23522
23 AL13-PRD-C1   115 nonlinear 125.25       90.77260      88.46154 16.970760       90.77260
24 AL13-PRD-C1   130 nonlinear 136.25      100.00000     100.00000 18.695906      100.00000
25 AL13-PRD-C2    25 nonlinear  60.25       30.83378      15.62500  6.911408       30.83378
26 AL13-PRD-C2    40 nonlinear  63.25       34.20411      25.00000  7.666869       34.20411
27 AL13-PRD-C2    55 nonlinear  72.75       44.72117      34.37500 10.024272       44.72117
28 AL13-PRD-C2    70 nonlinear  79.00       51.17759      43.75000 11.471481       51.17759
29 AL13-PRD-C2    85 nonlinear  88.25       62.29020      53.12500 13.962379       62.29020
30 AL13-PRD-C2   100 nonlinear  99.00       70.34380      62.50000 15.767597       70.34380
31 AL13-PRD-C2   115 nonlinear 107.00       75.67677      71.87500 16.962985       75.67677
32 AL13-PRD-C2   130 nonlinear 118.50       83.97401      81.25000 18.822816       83.97401
33 AL13-PRD-C2   145 nonlinear 128.25       92.73146      90.62500 20.785801       92.73146
34 AL13-PRD-C2   160 nonlinear 142.50      100.00000     100.00000 22.415049      100.00000
```

As you can see, not everyone has the same `percent_power` value. I would like to make everyone one the same increment according the `percent_power` column. For example, I would like to get `25 %, 50 %, 75 %, and 100 %`.
That means that the value has to be estimated if I understand well.
Here is an example for only 2 patients of what I would expect. Values in the other column have to be estimated if the exact `percent_power` doesn't exist.

```
            id power  training     hr percent_absVO2 percent_power    relVO2 percent_relVO2
1  AC12-PRD-C1    25    linear  88.75       49.34068      25.00000  8.797619       49.34068
2  AC12-PRD-C1    55    linear  99.75       63.51193      50.00000 11.324405       63.51193
3  AC12-PRD-C1    85    linear 118.75       80.05341      75.00000 14.273810       80.05341
4  AC12-PRD-C1   115    linear 135.75      100.00000     100.00000 17.830357      100.00000
5  AC12-PRD-C2    40    linear  89.25       43.49889      25.00000  8.649764       43.49889
6  AC12-PRD-C2    70    linear 102.25       63.00964      50.00000 12.529481       63.00964
7  AC12-PRD-C2   115    linear 129.25       89.34025      75.00000 17.765330       89.34025
16 AC12-PRD-C2   145    linear 147.50      100.00000     100.00000 19.885024      100.00000
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you show us your expected output?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my questions. thanks

Comment: Would you be so kind and `dput()` your data frame.

Comment: Do you mean remove some columns to make it clearer ? I have let the other column because we need it for the comprehension. I posted a comment below your answer. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not well defined, you want us to predict multiple variables, but you do not tell us how, which is crucial. There are infinitely many ways in which you could "predict" these missing values. For ex. your variables "percent" are limited within 0 and 100, which you have to include in your prediction, or you will get nonsense results.

Having said that, I will do just that and predict all these variables using a simple linear model, which assumes a linear relationship between all your numeric variables and `percent_power`.

First create a linear model to make your predictions

```
mod=lm(cbind(power,hr,percent_absVO2,relVO2,percent_relVO2)~percent_power*id+training,data=df)
```

then create your dataset with all the combinations that you want to predict

```
tst=setNames(
  data.frame(
    expand.grid(unique(df[,"id"]),unique(df[,"training"]),seq(25,100,25))
  )
,c("id","training","percent_power")
)
```

and then predict

```
cbind(
  tst,
  predict(mod,tst)
)

            id  training percent_power  power        hr percent_absVO2    relVO2
1  AC12-PRD-C1    linear            25  28.75  88.08482       49.30491  8.791242
2  AC12-PRD-C2    linear            25  36.25  86.88333       43.57464  8.664828
3  AL13-PRD-C1    linear            25  32.50  70.24554       42.60440  7.965278
4  AL13-PRD-C2    linear            25  40.00  63.65909       36.80735  8.250386
5  AC12-PRD-C1 nonlinear            25  28.75  88.08482       49.30491  8.791242
6  AC12-PRD-C2 nonlinear            25  36.25  86.88333       43.57464  8.664828
7  AL13-PRD-C1 nonlinear            25  32.50  70.24554       42.60440  7.965278
8  AL13-PRD-C2 nonlinear            25  40.00  63.65909       36.80735  8.250386
9  AC12-PRD-C1    linear            50  57.50 103.65774       65.64847 11.705357
10 AC12-PRD-C2    linear            50  72.50 106.05556       63.13669 12.554745
11 AL13-PRD-C1    linear            50  65.00  91.71230       61.50428 11.498782
12 AL13-PRD-C2    linear            50  80.00  88.20455       57.97911 12.996047
13 AC12-PRD-C1 nonlinear            50  57.50 103.65774       65.64847 11.705357
14 AC12-PRD-C2 nonlinear            50  72.50 106.05556       63.13669 12.554745
15 AL13-PRD-C1 nonlinear            50  65.00  91.71230       61.50428 11.498782
16 AL13-PRD-C2 nonlinear            50  80.00  88.20455       57.97911 12.996047
17 AC12-PRD-C1    linear            75  86.25 119.23065       81.99203 14.619473
18 AC12-PRD-C2    linear            75 108.75 125.22778       82.69873 16.444662
19 AL13-PRD-C1    linear            75  97.50 113.17907       80.40415 15.032285
20 AL13-PRD-C2    linear            75 120.00 112.75000       79.15088 17.741707
21 AC12-PRD-C1 nonlinear            75  86.25 119.23065       81.99203 14.619473
22 AC12-PRD-C2 nonlinear            75 108.75 125.22778       82.69873 16.444662
23 AL13-PRD-C1 nonlinear            75  97.50 113.17907       80.40415 15.032285
24 AL13-PRD-C2 nonlinear            75 120.00 112.75000       79.15088 17.741707
25 AC12-PRD-C1    linear           100 115.00 134.80357       98.33560 17.533588
26 AC12-PRD-C2    linear           100 145.00 144.40000      102.26077 20.334578
27 AL13-PRD-C1    linear           100 130.00 134.64583       99.30403 18.565789
28 AL13-PRD-C2    linear           100 160.00 137.29545      100.32264 22.487368
29 AC12-PRD-C1 nonlinear           100 115.00 134.80357       98.33560 17.533588
30 AC12-PRD-C2 nonlinear           100 145.00 144.40000      102.26077 20.334578
31 AL13-PRD-C1 nonlinear           100 130.00 134.64583       99.30403 18.565789
32 AL13-PRD-C2 nonlinear           100 160.00 137.29545      100.32264 22.487368
   percent_relVO2
1        49.30491
2        43.57464
3        42.60440
4        36.80735
5        49.30491
6        43.57464
7        42.60440
8        36.80735
9        65.64847
10       63.13669
11       61.50428
12       57.97911
13       65.64847
14       63.13669
15       61.50428
16       57.97911
17       81.99203
18       82.69873
19       80.40415
20       79.15088
21       81.99203
22       82.69873
23       80.40415
24       79.15088
25       98.33560
26      102.26077
27       99.30403
28      100.32264
29       98.33560
30      102.26077
31       99.30403
32      100.32264
```

Note how the percents have gone over 100, which was to be expected, given our model.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I got this message `Error: unexpected ')' in ")"`

Comment: @MaxStudent You are right, I forgot to paste one `)` in the expand.grid line.

Answer (score 0):

When I got you correct, that is what you want.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- structure(list(id = c("AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", 
"AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C2", 
"AC12-PRD-C2", "AC12-PRD-C2", "AC12-PRD-C2", "AC12-PRD-C2", "AC12-PRD-C2", 
"AC12-PRD-C2", "AC12-PRD-C2", "AC12-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", 
"AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", 
"AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C2", 
"AL13-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C2", "AL13-PRD-C2"
), power = c(25, 40, 55, 70, 85, 100, 115, 25, 40, 55, 70, 85, 
100, 115, 130, 145, 25, 40, 55, 70, 85, 100, 115, 130, 25, 40, 
55, 70, 85, 100, 115, 130, 145), training = c("linear", "linear", 
"linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", 
"linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", 
"nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", 
"nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", 
"nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", "nonlinear", 
"nonlinear", "nonlinear"), hr = c(88.75, 93.25, 99.75, 109.75, 
118.75, 127, 135.75, 84.25, 89.25, 96.25, 102.25, 110.75, 118.25, 
129.25, 136.25, 147.5, 69.5, 73, 83.25, 93.75, 104.5, 114.25, 
125.25, 136.25, 60.25, 63.25, 72.75, 79, 88.25, 99, 107, 118.5, 
128.25), percent_absVO2 = c(49.34068, 54.7321, 63.51193, 71.79102, 
80.05341, 89.85144, 100, 40.10378, 43.49889, 49.54781, 63.00964, 
70.02224, 80.11861, 89.34025, 93.29874, 100, 41.36691, 46.82515, 
53.48764, 61.58899, 71.91117, 84.23522, 90.7726, 100, 30.83378, 
34.20411, 44.72117, 51.17759, 62.2902, 70.3438, 75.67677, 83.97401, 
92.73146), percent_power = c(21.73913, 34.78261, 47.82609, 60.86957, 
73.91304, 86.95652, 100, 17.24138, 27.58621, 37.93103, 48.27586, 
58.62069, 68.96552, 79.31034, 89.65517, 100, 19.23077, 30.76923, 
42.30769, 53.84615, 65.38462, 76.92308, 88.46154, 100, 15.625, 
25, 34.375, 43.75, 53.125, 62.5, 71.875, 81.25, 90.625), relVO2 = c(8.797619, 
9.758929, 11.324405, 12.800595, 14.273810, 16.020833, 
17.830357, 7.974646, 8.649764, 9.852594, 12.529481, 
13.923939, 15.931604, 17.765330, 18.552476, 19.885024, 
7.733918, 8.754386, 10.000000, 11.514620, 13.444444, 
15.748538, 16.970760, 18.695906, 6.911408, 7.666869, 
10.024272, 11.471481, 13.962379, 15.767597, 16.962985, 
18.822816, 20.785801), percent_relVO2 = c(49.34068, 54.7321, 
63.51193, 71.79102, 80.05341, 89.85144, 100, 40.10378, 43.49889, 
49.54781, 63.00964, 70.02224, 80.11861, 89.34025, 93.29874, 100, 
41.36691, 46.82515, 53.48764, 61.58899, 71.91117, 84.23522, 90.7726, 
100, 30.83378, 34.20411, 44.72117, 51.17759, 62.2902, 70.3438, 
75.67677, 83.97401, 92.73146)), row.names = c(NA, -33L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>% dplyr::mutate(., percent_power = dplyr::case_when(
    percent_absVO2 < 25 ~ 0,
    percent_absVO2 < 50 ~ 25,
    percent_absVO2 < 75 ~ 50,
    percent_absVO2 < 100 ~ 75,
    TRUE ~ 100
))
```

Comment: Thank you @tacoman. Your answer makes correctly the 25, 50, 75, 100 % in the `percent_power` column. However, I would like that the other columns adapt their respective value to match with the %. We might need to estimate the value for each column. For example, the first individual at 21%, when we adjust it for 25, I would like that each value in all other column to be estimated. Thank you.